# Angular app fails to build on server side correctly

Tags: angular, upgrade, server-side-rendering, ivy, prerender

this is the error I am getting after i run the command:

npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr

The app is currently running on Angular 10, but has been updated from Angular 9. And before that from Angular 8, 7 and 6. I am guessing this is some kind of upgrade/migration mismatch?

I haven't made any progress on the error, always keep getting stuck on it or on Firebase if i disable Ivy. If anyone has had something similar to this, please do share your experience.

```
Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped
    at View.engine (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:47492:23)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:132944:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:128994:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:128946:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:140541:7)
    at C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:138:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:132372:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:131293:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:131268:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Blazhe\apps\angular\myapp\client\dist\server.js:132372:5)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run client:server:production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^7.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "v7.0.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.50",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^9.3.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.x",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^7.8.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng-click-outside": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-disqus": "^2.4.3",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^9.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "screenfull": "^5.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.4",
    "@schematics/angular": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~14.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "src/tsconfig.server.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "client-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
//enableProdMode();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular-universal getting error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850267/angular-universal-getting-error-you-must-pass-in-a-ngmodule-or-ngmodulefactory)

Comment: can you show your package.json?

Comment: izmaylovdev, i added it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your `server.ts`, `angular.json` and `main.ts` files? Also, how do you generate the `server.js` bundle? Starting with angular v9, you don't need to build server and client bundle separately

Comment: David, added them. Thanks!